# python subprocess - why causes a space in the arguments an error

Tags: python, subprocess

This does work nice:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["ls","-l"])
```

But this line causes an error:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call(["ls"," -l"])
ls: cannot access  -l: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 558, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', ' -l']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Why does this happen?

In unix I can write:

```
ls                                           -l
```

with many spaces between `ls` and `-l`

I use Python 3.4.5 on Centos 6

Comment: From shell try `~$ 'ls' ' -l'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In unix I can write:

You don't write that *in unix*. You write that **in a shell**. The *shell* parses that output and produces a list, after collapsing the whitespace. It then passes the equivalent of `['ls', '-l']` (no spaces!) to the `ls` process.

Different shells can treat whitespace differently. Most let you *escape* whitespace by using quotes or backslashes. So the following fails just as much in a shell as it does in Python:

```
$ ls ' -l'
ls:  -l: No such file or directory
```

With `subprocess`, unless you set `shell=True`, you are not passing the arguments through the shell, you pass this *straight* to the `ls` process that is started. So you have to deliver those arguments the way `ls` expects them to be delivered, with no spaces before the `-` for options.

If you need to split out commands and arguments in roughly the same way the shell does, use the [`shlex` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("ls          -l")
['ls', '-l']
>>> shlex.split("ls ' -l'")
['ls', ' -l']
```